# why docking not correctly working for existing groupboxes in win forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an existing win from with two group boxes groupbox1 at top while groupbox2 at bottom.now i am facing problem when using docking.when i dock groupbox1 to top and groupbox2 dock to fill then groupbox2 occupying whole height. i have tried to change size and location of groupbox2 using designer as well as property window, but when i came back to designer view its size and location restored to default as earlier.
Then i created a new form and place groupbox1 and dock it to top,and then groupbox2 and dock it to fill now arrangement is correct.
Now i want to know how to correct this layout problem for existing form.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *Document Outline* window to change the order of groupboxes.
I remember similar case with other controls and the changing of order helped.

Comment: Thank you so much that's working, one more request i want to know why this is happening ??

Comment: I think the order in *Document Outline* window defines the order of control creations and initializations in *InitializeComponent()* method. And if a control with *Fill* value is initialized first than it has no knowledge about the *Top* control. So it fills the whole parent control. I'm not sure, just an attempted explanation for myself.